# Overprovisioned teams in services companies

Tags: project-management, performance-reviews, performance, planning, competition

Is it common for managers to pack more engineers into a team than there are tickets to solve in the pipeline in order to generate contests and pit engineers against eachother and get better delivery times?

How common is this and how can I as an individual contributor avoid it? Do I keep moving to a different team every time it gets overprovisioned, every time losing all the time I had invested in acquiring skills for that team?

Comment: Did they actually hire more people, or are the number of tasks just fluctuating? I would not call it "overstaffing" if a team is equipped to handle the highest annual workload well and is kinda bored during off-season. That is a business decision that makes sense. Or are you bored all year long and they still hire more people?

Comment: I got told I did 19 tickets, and my team-mates 34 and 31 respectively. There is a pipeline and team-mates are literally scrambling to grab the easy tickets first. Decided to move to a different team where this type of stack-ranking doesn't happen, until it does. If it happens again in the new team I'm thinking of dropping the contract altogether.

Comment: Were there another 15 tickets you *could* have done? Or were there simply no more tickets? Did you ask your boss for tickets when you ran out? Or is it that you don't like to be compared on ticket numbers? Does comparing on numbers alone even make sense for you? Are all tickets the same size? You may get better answers if you start your question at the beginning, it seems you have already drawn a conclusion for yourself, but I am not sure we would draw the same. Offering more information might give you a chance to get answers outside of your current conclusion.

Comment: Not all tickets are the same size and inside the team, there is strong reluctance against taking big tickets because there is a daily status meeting every day. This generates the following dynamic: constant refreshing the JIRA active spring board to pick the newest easiest ticket possible.

Comment: Did you talk about that with anybody? What did your manager say when you brought that up?

Comment: @nvoigt it's not that I don't like being compared on ticket numbers. this contract is below market pay, I've already told the manager this, and the expectations are simply not aligned. I have also asked the manager what exactly would be the success formula here? That all 3 team members do the exact same number of tickets? That they constantly split tickets between them such that none would stand out as an outlier? They did not answer my questions.
Going back to your comparing tickets: I'm not trying to build Rome or move mountains, I'm simply trying to pay my bills with this job.

Comment: It seems to me, your problem is more with how ticket distribution is handled and how contribution to the team is evaluated, than any problem with too many people on the team for the amount of tickets you have.

Comment: There were at least 2 instances when I had assigned myself to a ticket and one of the team-members re-assigned themselves to it and then excusing themselves that they took my ticket and another instance where the other team member is asking me about the status of a ticket even though he's not a manager and I never asked them about their tickets ever.

Comment: I can see that that is not a nice way to work and maybe can be solved or maybe not. But you may want to edit your question to reflect all that, because it seems your problem is not actually how many people are on your team or how many tickets there are.

Comment: I have worked 25 years in the it industry and I have always felt the same. Everybody else is running around complaining about how much they have to, while nothing is being done.

Answer (score 5):

I would say 'no, this is not common' - An Engineer - whether it's a mechanical engineer, a Systems Engineer, an Engineering Engineer etc. is generally quite an expensive resource (I know my Salary is nothing to scoff at) and so having Engineers sat around twiddling their thumbs is *generally* a big waste of a salary.

So either they aren't 'proper' engineers (that is, commanding an Engineers salary) - or there's something more to this than you've not elaborated on.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it common for managers to pack more engineers into a team than
> there are tickets to solve in the pipeline in order to generate
> contests and pit engineers against eachother and get better delivery
> times?

Management wants to create a team that addresses tickets for the least cost, while also meeting the service level agreements. There are of course managers that don't do this well.

Contests or the like should be used to improve the key metrics that they are being measured against.

> How common is this and how can I as an individual contributor avoid
> it? Do I keep moving to a different team every time it gets
> overprovisioned, every time losing all the time I had invested in
> acquiring skills for that team?

I think it would be worse to have a team that was too small, or a team that didn't have people with the right skill sets.  They would struggle to meet the expectations for the team.

One reason that the team could be overstaffed is if the company uses the positions on the team as a place to park people between projects. The get some productive work instead of doing nothing. Doing this does add an additional task on the managers to not let this get out of control.

I wouldn't switch teams because they have two many employees, unless I also thought that there were signs the team was going to be reduced in size because they were too expensive. Jumping on my own schedule would be preferable to getting cut unexpectedly.